# How to set the value of a field when creating a user, based on the value of the current user

Tags: django

I'm creating a form where users can register additional users, and I need to automatically pass the foreign key (organization) of the current user to the new user being created.

I'm relatively new to Django, but I believe the issue is with the following line in the forms:

"user.organization = self.instance.organization"

Model

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=(('org_admin', 'Admin'),('org_user','User'),('client_admin','Client Admin'),('client_user','Client User')))

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()
```

View

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserOrgCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            messages.success(request, f'User has been created')
            # return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserOrgCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Form

```
class UserOrgCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    password1 = None
    password2 = None

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'user_type')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_unusable_password()
        user.organization = self.instance.organization
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

I need the new user to inherit the organization of the current user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your form is not based on existing instance (not passed when creating form instance), you cannot refer to that while saving.

You can do what you want in view as below

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserOrgCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save(commit=False)
            new_user.organization = request.user.organization
            new_user.save()
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            messages.success(request, f'User has been created')
            # return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserOrgCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Be sure to wrap the view with the `login_required` decorator to ensure `request.user` is a logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage `commit=False` [parameter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method). This won't save the form to the database until `.save()` is called a second time.

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserOrgCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.organization = request.user.organization
            obj.save()
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            messages.success(request, f'User has been created')
            # return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserOrgCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the `request.user.organisation` form the form save.

```
class UserOrgCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    password1 = None
    password2 = None

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'user_type')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_unusable_password()
        user.organization = current_user.organization
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.current_user = kwargs.pop("current_user", None)
        super(UserOrgCreationForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
```

And from the view:

```
def register(request):
    form = UserOrgCreationForm(request.POST or None, current_user=request.user)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        messages.success(request, f'User has been created')
        # return redirect('login')

    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```